# exec() does not return to PHP process

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I am running FFMPEG from PHP with the EXEC command. I am working on a XAMP stack.

```
$command = 'ffmpeg -y -i input output 2>logfile';
exec ($command);
// after FFMPEG handling...
```

As you can see, I am redirecting FFMPEG's output to a log file.

This works fine from smaller video files (up to approximately 10 MB).

**My problem is that for larger video files, any PHP commands after the exec() will not get executed.** Note however, that the FFMPEG process works just fine. The log file shows that FFMPEG terminates OK, and the resulting output file is also good.

My max_execution_time is set to 10800, which should be plenty (and then some). Anyway, as I understand from [max_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system() ... is not included
>   when determining the maximum time that the script has been running.

**Update:** error logs state: *Premature end of script*

What is going on?

Comment: Anything in the logs? If it is a timeout, it will show up there.

Comment: Try changing `2>logfile` to `1>logfile 2>&1`.  That way both STDOUT and STDERR end up in the same file.

Comment: To be honest, I have tried accessing them but failed. I am on Dreamhost VPS...

Comment: The error logs simply state: Premature end of script. I am not even sure that this corresponds with this exec problem, although it does appear that way. This does not help me any...

Comment: I did change **2>logfile** to **1>logfile 2>&1**. But the FFMPEG process ends just fine. So that did not yield any new information.

Comment: I tried to change the IPCCommTimeout variable. But I am not sure that Dreamhost allows me to do this. Is there way to check the new value?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this? Or at least the root cause? I am having the exact same issue and cannot figure out why the script gets terminated only for a large video...

Comment: No, this was never resolved...

Comment: I found this, deals with very similar problem...and works for me: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755568/error-in-jquery-upload-file-due-to-ffmpeg-conversion-using-php`. I am getting another error though - `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience`...still investigating what is means and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I am not actively working on this project at this time. But I will keep it in mind!